# Problem connecting to a Jupyter Notebook on a remote machine

Tags: python, ssh, jupyter-notebook, remote-server

I can ssh into a remote machine.

I then try to connect to a jupyter notebook job that I started on one of the nodes of the remote machine:

`ssh -L 8069:localhost:8069 me@remote.machine ssh -L 8069:localhost:8069 me@node14`

This has always worked fine in the past.

When I execute this lately, nothing happens until I eventually get a time out message. If I cancel it and then try to simply ssh into the remote machine again, it again does nothing until I get the error message:

`ssh: connect to host remote.machine port 22: Connection timed out`

I am trying to figure out if this is a problem at my end or at the remote machine. If it's the latter I can't understand why I am able to ssh to the remote machine fine *until* I try the

`ssh -L 8069:localhost:8069 me@remote.machine ssh -L 8069:localhost:8069 me@node14`

connection.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a double `ssh` connection: one to `remote.machine` and then another one to `node14`.
The problem seems to be the `ssh` process in the `node14` machine.  So, you can connect to the first machine but no to the second one.  Ask your administrator to enable the `sshd` process in `node14`

You can test this case by logging into `remote.machine` via:

`ssh -L 8069:localhost:8069 me@remote.machine`.

Once you get shell access you can try the connection to `node14` via:

`ssh -L 8069:localhost:8069 me@node14`.

According to the description, this last try should fail with the timeout.